# Changing printer preference using vb6?

Tags: vb6, printing

I am having a problem when my program is installed to another computer, where its printer preference is different, where my data report accepts Letter size 8.2 * 11 in, because when the printer preference is different the data report well not show and gives an error saying the page width is larger than paper width, does anyone know how to fix this problem.

i tried this code but it didn't work

`Printer.PaperSize = vbPRPSLetter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Microsoft KnowledgeBase article [FIX: Error Message "Report Width Is Larger Than the Paper Width" When Showing Data Report in Landscape](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261193/EN-US/)

> When using the Show method of Data
>   Report to preview the report, the page
>   orientation defaults to the default
>   printer settings on the local
>   computer. Therefore, if the
>   orientation of the default printer
>   settings is set to Portrait of
>   standard Letter paper and your report
>   width is more than 8.5 inches wide,
>   the following error occurs:  Report
>   Width is Larger than the Paper Width.

The solution appears to be setting `Orientation` before using the Data Report. Change `DataReport1` to the name of your data report.

```
DataReport1.Orientation = rptOrientLandscape
DataReport1.Show
```

---

**EDIT** Another suggestion: Microsoft [offer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q198901/) a free DLL that allows you to change the **default** settings for the printer. You could try using that free DLL in your project, then do something like this code below before using the data report. Microsoft say "this DLL is **particularly useful when dealing with the Data Report**, which reads the default printer orientation prior to displaying or printing a report."

```
  Set obj = New PrinterControl
  obj.ChngOrientationLandscape
```

Comment: it gives me an error, saying Variable not defined when compile

Comment: @Mahmoud Change `DataReport1` to the name of your data report.

Comment: i know i changed it, but i how to add the dll to the software, cause i am trying to register it on my windows 7 but i keep getting an error, and when i follow microsoft method i keep getting an error, what do you suggest

Comment: @Mahmoud about the "variable not defined": do you have Visual Basic 6 **service pack 6** installed? If not I suggest you install the service pack. About the error on registering the DLL. Are you logged on as administrator? Can you tell us the exact error message please?

Comment: i did update my visual basic 6 to service pack 6, and i still get error, about the error that show while registering the dll is 
`The Module c:/users/nobody/Desktop/pageset.dll was loaded but the call to dllregisterserver failed with error code 0x80004005`

Answer (score 1):

-Can you just switch to a custom paper size?

```
Printer.PaperSize = 256
Printer.Width = 11808  '(8.2 * 1440)
Printer.Height = 15840 '(11 * 1440)
```

-Are you sure the error isn't related
to the maximum print width of the
report itself? Many printers have a max print width
that forces 1/4" margins on either
side of a paper. Which in your case forces your printable area to be 7.7" max. Quickest way to
check would be to temporarily set
the print wide to a lower value and
see if it works.

-Another possibility could be permissions to the printer. If it's a shared network resource it may be locked down and be rejecting the changes to the paper settings and throwing an inaccurate error msg.

Comment: Hey There, the report well only print when i change my printer preference to letter, then the datareport well open and i tried your method i keep gettting an error on `printer.papersize = 256`

Answer (score 0):

To change Printer orientation at runtime, we need to install VB6 Service pack 6

Use this code

```
DataReport1.Orientation = rptOrientLandscape
DataReport1.Show
```

This will work fine